# search value within range in column fields

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table in database like following

```
id  |  range        | price 
1   |  11.00-11.99  | 2.78  
2   |  12.00-12.99  | 3.65  
3   |  13.00-13.99  | 2.90  
4   |  14.00-14.99  | 1.56
```

and I have to search value `13.65` in `range` column. Is there any way to directly search in mysql query

thanks in advance

Comment: Think about a table redesing, where you have a min and a max value for your range

Comment: I mean you should have a struchture like id, range_min, range_max, Price, so you can query every value by ist own

Comment: isn't there any way to search in single fields because there is a lot of records in range. I can't modify existing table that is using in multiple areas

Comment: what data type is of range column?

Comment: what is result of `13.65` in above records?

Comment: it is showing nothing empty result set and data type is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring_index` to separate range and use that in `between` clause.

You can also use `between left(range,5) and right(range,5)`, which could be faster. Test it for yourself.

```
select * from your_table
where 13.65 between 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`,'-',1) 
 and SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`,'-',-1);
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(range,'-',1)` will give you value before first `-` and

Note: As suggested by others in comment, you should consider redesigning the tables structure, but if that is not possible, you should create index on `range` column for both `left` and `right` of `-`. I would leave you to figure out how to do that but that will significantly improve the performance of the query.

Comment: Note that this solution cannot benefit from idexes. In consequence, it is slow and horrible - but, it does at least point to a way in which the OP might go about fixing their broken design.

Comment: I completely agree with you on design part, but I know it is not easily feasible to implement on an already existing project. While OP and others should take this into consideration while designing the tables, not much can be done when you get requirements like this, except come up with a solution. Not very sure on MySQL, but I believe they can create index on `left` and `right` of `range` column for faster search. Will mention this in the answer as well.

Comment: In MySQL, functions cannot use indexes.

Comment: @Strawberry  Hmm. That's a bummer.